# Implement Websocket using boost::asio::beast with serialized writes

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, websocket

Here's a proposal implementation of websocket using `boost::asio::beast` that is thread-safe to parallel writes.

In this example below, the `async_write` can be triggered in response to server notification (I) or from periodic keepalive calls implemented on a dedicated thread (II).
I'd like to here your comments regarding my implementation and especially to the use of `strand` in order to serialize the async_writes and make them thread-safe.

Thanks !

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/strand.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>

#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>

#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

#include <cstdlib>

class ServerCommunication {
public:
    explicit ServerCommunication(const char *host, const char *port);

    void Stop();
    void Run(std::vector<std::thread> &v);
    void Send(std::string data);

private:
    void ConnectAndListen(const boost::asio::yield_context &yield);
    void SenderService(const boost::asio::yield_context &yield);

    bool is_connected_ = false;
    std::string ip_;
    std::string port_;
    boost::asio::io_context io_context_;
    
    void on_write(boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred);

    boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> strand_;


    boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::beast::tcp_stream> ws_;
    boost::beast::error_code ec_;
    
    void fail(char const* op) { std::cerr << op << ": " << ec_.message() << "\n"; }
    
};


ServerCommunication::ServerCommunication(const char *ip, const char *port)
    : ip_(ip), port_(port) , ws_(io_context_) , strand_(boost::asio::make_strand(io_context_)) { }

void ServerCommunication::Stop() {
    boost::asio::spawn(
        io_context_,
        [this](const boost::asio::yield_context &yield) {
        ws_.async_close(boost::beast::websocket::close_code::normal, yield[ec_]);

        if(ec_) {
            return fail("close");
        }
    });
    
    io_context_.stop();
}

void ServerCommunication::ConnectAndListen(const boost::asio::yield_context &yield) {

    boost::beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));
    
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_context_);

    auto const results = resolver.async_resolve(ip_, port_, yield[ec_]);

    auto ep = boost::beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).async_connect(results, yield[ec_]);
    if(ec_) return fail("connect");

    // Update the host_ string. This will provide the value of the
    // Host HTTP header during the WebSocket handshake.
    // See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.4
    auto address = ip_ + std::to_string(ep.port());

    // Turn off the timeout on the tcp_stream, because
    // the websocket stream has its own timeout system.
    boost::beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_never();

    // Set suggested timeout settings for the websocket
    ws_.set_option(
        boost::beast::websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(
            boost::beast::role_type::client));

    // Set a decorator to change the User-Agent of the handshake
    ws_.set_option(boost::beast::websocket::stream_base::decorator(
        [](boost::beast::websocket::request_type& req)
        {
            req.set(boost::beast::http::field::user_agent,
                std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
                    " websocket-client-me");
        }));

    // Perform the websocket handshake
    ws_.async_handshake(address, "/ws", yield[ec_]);
    if(ec_) return fail("handshake");

    is_connected_ = true;
    for (;;) {
        boost::beast::flat_buffer buffer;

        // Read a message into our buffer
        ws_.async_read(buffer, yield[ec_]);
        if(ec_) return fail("read");

        std::cout << boost::beast::make_printable(buffer.data()) << std::endl;

        //### The first async_write is triggered from incoming server data (I).
        Send("Ack");

    }
}

void ServerCommunication::Run(std::vector<std::thread> &v) {
    boost::asio::spawn(io_context_,
                       [this](const boost::asio::yield_context &yield) {
        this->ConnectAndListen(yield);
    });
    
    v.emplace_back([this] {
        this->io_context_.run();
        });
}

void ServerCommunication::on_write(
    boost::system::error_code ec,
    std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
}

void ServerCommunication::Send(std::string data) {
    ws_.async_write(boost::asio::buffer(data),
                    boost::asio::bind_executor(strand_, [this] (boost::system::error_code ec,
                                                                std::size_t bytes_transferred)
                                    { this->on_write(ec, bytes_transferred);}));
    
    if(ec_) { fail("write"); }
}



int main() {    
    std::vector<std::thread> v;
    v.reserve(1);

    // Connect to local server that listen to arbitrary port 44444
    ServerCommunication serverCommunication_("0.0.0.0" , "44444");
    serverCommunication_.Run(v);
    

    sleep(5);
    std::thread t([&] () {
        for (;;) {
            sleep(1);
            // ### this will simulate the on-demand async_writes (II).
            serverCommunication_.Send("ZZZZZ");
        }
    });
    
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```